# How to tell behave at the command line about multiple steps/ directories

Tags: python, bdd, gherkin

We are using Behave to bind our Gherkin Feature files to Python. I am running into a problem where we are starting to duplicate our `step_impl` functions, and I want to eliminate the code duplication, but I am not able to figure out how to tell behave about a `steps/` directory that is not immediately next to the feature file. Below is our feature file structure:

```
all_components/features/huge.feature
all_components/features/steps/steps.py
component1/features/little.feature
component1/features/steps/steps.py
```

I want to run Behave on the `huge.feature` and find step implementations under `component1/features/steps/`, and not just `all_components/features/steps.py`, so that individual component features and steps remain intact, and I can reuse steps in the component features for my `huge.feature`

```
$ behave all_components/features/
```

Comment: I think a solution that kinda works for me is to add a __init__.py so I can import the steps.py in the little.feature as a package.